# Access Select - Combine table1 with summed values of table2

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I've two tables in Access 2010:

Tab1:

```
Key|ValTab1
  1|    100
  2|    200
  3|    300
```

Tab2:

```
Key|ValTab2
  1|   1000
  1|   7000
  3|   3000
  4|   4000
```

Desired Result:

```
Key|    Val
  1|   8100
  2|    200
  3|   3300
```

Is it possible to do this without selecting everything into one table and then group everything (in Microsoft Access)? Something like

```
SELECT Tab1.Key,Sum(Tab1.ValTab1+IIF(Tab2.ValTab2 Is Null,0,Tab2.ValTab2)) AS Val
FROM Tab1 LEFT JOIN Tab2 
ON Tab1.Key = Tab2.Key
GROUP BY Tab1.Key;
```

But this results in Key 1/Val 8**2**00

**Problem #2:**

Extend Tab1 to

```
Cat|Key|ValTab1
  1|  1|    100
  1|  2|    200
  1|  3|    300
  2|  4|     20
  3|  5|      1
```

Is it possible to make a connection from Cat using Tab1.Key=Tab2.Key to get Sum(ValTab1+ValTab2)?

> Applying FuzzyTree's Solution `max(tab1.val) + sum(tab2.val)` for Problem #1:

This would mean something like

```
SELECT Tab1.Cat, Max(Tab1.ValTab1) + Sum(IIF(Tab2.ValTab2 Is Null,0,Tab2.ValTab2)) AS Val
FROM Tab1 LEFT JOIN Tab2 
ON Tab1.Key = Tab2.Key
GROUP BY Tab1.Cat;
```

With the desired result:

```
Cat|  Val
  1|11600
  2| 4020
  3|    1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the keys in `tab1` are unique, then you should add their values only once, which you can do with `sum(tab1.val) + sum(tab2.val)`

i.e.

```
SELECT Tab1.Key, Sum(Tab1.ValTab1) + Sum(Tab2.ValTab2) AS Val
FROM Tab1 LEFT JOIN Tab2 
ON Tab1.Key = Tab2.Key
GROUP BY Tab1.Key;
```

Comment: That works. Is it possible to group that by an other column? let's say you add column `Key 2` with values `categ1` to Tab1 (each entry) and do it like `SELECT Tab1.Key2, Max(Tab1.ValTab1) + Sum(IIF(Tab2.ValTab2 Is Null,0,Tab2.ValTab2)) AS Val FROM Tab1 LEFT JOIN Tab2 ON Tab1.Key = Tab2.Key GROUP BY Tab1.Key2`? As a result `categ1|11600`. Actually `max` cant be used here.

Comment: @dan i don't understand the question. it may be clearer if you open a separate question

Comment: This results in `Cat=1, Val=11700` because `Cat=1,Key=1,ValTab1=100` is counted twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think a correlated subquery might be easiest in this case:

```
select tabl1.*,
       (tab1.valtab1 +
        (select sum(valtab2)
         from tab2
         where tab2.key = tab1.key
        )
       ) as val
from tab1;
```

You may need to use `nz()`:

```
select tabl1.*,
       (tab1.valtab1 +
        nz((select sum(valtab2)
            from tab2
            where tab2.key = tab1.key
           ), 0)
       ) as val
from tab1;
```